# Polyline not shown on GoogleMap Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

I am trying to build ActivityTracker application for Android using Xamarin. I have already got access to Google Maps Api and can get current device location. Next step is connect locations I got into a polyline, but Polyline is not visible on map.

Here is code I tried

```
private Polyline polyline;
public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        _map = map;
        _map.MyLocationEnabled = true;
        _map.TrafficEnabled = true;
        _map.SetIndoorEnabled(true);
        PolylineOptions poly = new PolylineOptions()
            .InvokeColor(Color.Red)
            .InvokeWidth(5)
            .Visible(true)
            .InvokeZIndex(30);
        poly.Add(new LatLng(95, 50));
        poly.Add(new LatLng(90, 55));
        poly.Add(new LatLng(100, 50));

        polyline = _map.AddPolyline(poly);
        _map.MyLocationChange += MyLocationChanged; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good, but coordinates of polyline points is bad: Google Maps using WGS 84 Web [Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Web_Mercator) with truncated latitudes of `Latmax = ±85.05113°`, so there is just no point with coordinates `LatLng(95, 50)` (`95` - too big for latitude) and `LatLng(90, 55)` and `LatLng(100, 50)`. Your coordinates should be from `(-89.99,-179.99)` to `(89.99,179.99)`. Try, for example use `55, 60` and `70` instead of `95, 90` and `100`:

```
private Polyline polyline;
public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        _map = map;
        _map.MyLocationEnabled = true;
        _map.TrafficEnabled = true;
        _map.SetIndoorEnabled(true);
        PolylineOptions poly = new PolylineOptions()
            .InvokeColor(Color.Red)
            .InvokeWidth(5)
            .Visible(true)
            .InvokeZIndex(30);
        poly.Add(new LatLng(55, 50));
        poly.Add(new LatLng(60, 55));
        poly.Add(new LatLng(70, 50));

        polyline = _map.AddPolyline(poly);
        _map.MyLocationChange += MyLocationChanged; 
    }
```